# Problem h:selectOneMenu and event onSelect

Tags: jsf

does anybody knows why I am not reaching this alert??

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="lang" binding="#{mybind}" onSelect="javascript:alert('Reacheable??')" >
```

in [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/h/selectOneMenu.html) says that it is available.
Thanks in advance

Comment: did you try removing "javascript:" ?

Answer (score 0):

my code is OK

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="creditBank" value="#{fundTranferExt.creditBank}" onchange="alert('Reacheable??')">
    <f:selectItems value="#{fExtBankList}"></f:selectItems>                             
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet but I would like to clarify [nguyên's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6093799/2617691) a little bit more. JSF isn't right on implementing onselect attribute. It generates HTML select element with "onselect" attribute but that one isn't valid for select. Instead of it you can use "onchange". That is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse but if user makes selection with keyboard the event is deferred until the element loses focus.
Also you have to remove "javascript:" from onchange value and write whole attribute name with lowercases. Value in onchange attribute is always JavaScript so you don't need to mentioned that explicitly:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="lang" binding="#{mybind}" onchange="alert('Reacheable??')" >
```